# XML DOM parsing with Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, parsing

I'm trying to parse this XML string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<response type="success">
   <lots>
      <lot>32342</lot>
      <lot>52644</lot>
   </lots>
 </response>
```

When I get the root node, which is "response", I use the method getChildNodes() which returns a NodeList of length 3. However what I'm confused about is the order the NodeList gets created in. I used some print statements to show whats in the list

```
Item length: 3
Item (0): [#text: 
]
Item (1): [lots: null]
Item (2): [#text: 
]
```

So the text node is first which is two levels below the root, then the next child of the root, and then the next text node.

Is there a particular order and/or reason the list is ordered in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the whitespace text surrounding the childnode "lots"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<response type="success">
{txt1}<lots>
         <lot>32342</lot>
         <lot>52644</lot>
      </lots>{txt2}
 </response>
```

Comment: I think your right, How would I parse the file to ignore whitespace?
I've tried setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);

Or is that something that will always be there?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the problem, I was using '\n' characters which was causing extra text nodes being parsed